# force mysql to clip an overflowing value of a variable - the way that c++ / java would

Tags: mysql, overflow

I am trying to write a mysql function that duplicates some C++ code I have. In C++ my function is meant to (sometimes) overflow, and C++ would simply allow those bytes to be an unsigned long as is intended.

```cpp
int32_t overflow_example(uint64_t someId) {
    const uint64_t A_BIG_NUMBER = 2862933555777941757ULL;
    uint64_t k = someId;
    k = (k * A_BIG_NUMBER);
    return k;
}
```

if I call the function: overflow_example(2147483647)
I would get:
-129020157

Is there any way to allow the same to happen in mysql? Instead, I now get

> [2022-07-13 21:15:47] [22001][1690] Data truncation: BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(k@2 * A_BIG_NUMBER@1)'

small sample below:

```mysql
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS overflow_example;
CREATE FUNCTION overflow_example(someId BIGINT UNSIGNED) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE A_BIG_NUMBER BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 2862933555777941757;
    DECLARE k BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT someId;

    SET SESSION sql_mode = '';
    SET k = (k * A_BIG_NUMBER);

    return k;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;

SET SESSION sql_mode = '';
set @just_truncate_me = overflow_example(CAST(2147483647 AS UNSIGNED));
select @just_truncate_me;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a15f66c91d40dbc1b86b3fed22a542f0)

Edit:
Since link couldn’t open, I’m editing the question to include the c++ code which uses arithmetic

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
 
    int main() {
        uint64_t int1 = 6148102993480692286475947779;
        uint64_t mostSignificant = int1 / 0x100000000 * 0x100000000;
        uint64_t int2 = int1 - mostSignificant;
        cout << (int32_t)int2 << endl;
 
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You may use DECIMAL of according length instead of BIGINT for parameters/variables and integer division (get reminder) for truncation.

Comment: @Akina thanks for the advice - would love to understand it better. How would I go from decimal to the "overflowed" version of the bigint that I would get in c++? Thanks again for taking the time

Comment: Imagine that the function output is defined as uint64_t, but your need to obtain the output which is produced by int32_t fn version, i.e. you need to convert uint64_t (`k`=6148102993480692286475947779) to -129020157 value (function output) in C++ using arithmetic operations with uint64_t values only. How should you do this for to obtain the same output?

Comment: I would mask the least significant bit half: https://ideone.com/X5flXc sorry still not sure how to fix the MySQL - can you give me more hints please :)

Comment: No-no. I have said - "using arithmetic operations". I.e. `+ - * /` only.

Comment: https://ideone.com/ouHVkh Something like this?

Comment: I cannot open your links. But it doesn't matter. If you can to perform this using arithmetic operations on C++ then you can to do the same calculations in SQL code. Something like `SET k=k MOD 2^32; IF k>=2^31 THEN SET k={arithmetic expression which creates negative value}; END IF;`

Comment: I edited the question to include the c++ arithmetic code. But I’m still confused about how to apply it to MySQL, because I’m multiplying a bigint and I don’t have a bigger thing that can hold it’s overflowed result(?). I feel like I’m still misunderstanding an important part

Comment: *`cout << (int32_t)int2 << endl;`* Datatype convertion is not arithmetic operation.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e85c052e0551590fab0eb66dfc866cd7

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand that mysql allowed 65 *digits* for decimal as opposed to bits - thanks again for your help